# We should use constants as descriptive variable name to initialize the default value of some field?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I found an implementation that has this structure  (extracted from the book [Head First Design Patterns.](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfdp/)):

```
public abstract class Pizza {
    String name;
    String dough;
    String souce;

    List<String> toppings = new ArrayList<>();

    //another methods ....

    public String getName() {
         return name;
    }
 }
```

Example of concrete class:

```
public class NYStyleCheesePizza extends Pizza {
    public NYStyleCheesePizza() {
        name = "NY Style Sauce and Cheese Pizza";
        dough = "Thin Crust Dough";
        souce = "Marina Souce";
        toppings.add("Grated Regiano Cheese");
    }
    .......
}
```

To formulate my question, I did this modification on the concrete class :

```
 public class NYStyleCheesePizza extends Pizza {
    private static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "NY Style Sauce and Cheese Pizza";
    private static final String DEFAULT_DOUGH = "Thin Crust Dough";
    private static final String DEFAULT_SOUCE = "Marina Souce";

    public NYStyleCheesePizza() {
        name = DEFAULT_NAME;
        dough = DEFAULT_DOUGH;
        souce = DEFAULT_SOUCE;
        toppings.add("Grated Regiano Cheese");
    } 
 ......
}
```

So, my question is:

**We should use constants as descriptive variable name to initialize the default  value of some field ?**

Comment: The example code in the book is probably simplistic for keeping the snippets short. But in general, extracting constants out as you've done, is a good practice; especially when the class is bigger.

Comment: Jesus, no. String literals are perfectly fine in this case. You can define a variable for it if the value is needed in two or more places.

Comment: Out of interest, what design pattern is the book trying to demonstrate with this code?

Comment: @Kyriacou FYI The book is traying to explain the factory pattern (chapter 4).  IMHO, for this case,  this is not a  relevant information.  I only use the code as exemple to formulate my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first assumption is that these default values are only used once, otherwise we would want constants for the sake of keeping our code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Given the aforementioned assumption, the decision to extract a `String` constant will always be a judgement call, because it's based on the subjective value of the constant's name, in terms of "descriptiveness". Basically, if you feel that `DEFAULT_NAME` enhances readability versus `name` (as assigned in the constructor) then by all means, extract the constant. Personally, I find the enhancement very slight in this case; but I will admit that without the constant, I need to combine `name` with the context of a constructor to derive what the constant conveys explicitly.

What you should never do is this (again assuming a single-use constant).
`private static final String NAME = "name";`
This constant adds no value in terms of readability, increases the scope of the String unnecessarily, and pollutes the namespace of the class.

Finally, note that `String` constants are a special case, because their value can communicate their meaning. Other (primitive) constants, such as integers, should probably always be extracted.